# How to grep over a variable

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a scenario like

```
VAR = `Some command brings the file path name and assigns it to VAR`
```

For example VAR can have value like /root/user/samp.txt

I want to grep command like

```
grep HI $VAR
```

This doesnt works gives an error saying cannot open /root/user/samp.txt
same error when tried cat $VAR.

How to handle this ?

I have given try

```
echo $VAR | grep HI
grep HI "$VAR"
```

Using korn shell

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Does $VAR contain arbitrary text, or does it contain a filename? Are you surprised about the "cannot open file" error message because it is supposed to be a valid file?

Comment: Have you test what is in $VAR by `echo "$VAR"`?

Comment: This works for me. Is there a permission or non-existence problem with  /root/user/samp.txt

Comment: You have first a permissions problem to solve, completely unrelated to your question... are you trying to access files in /root as a normal user??  Try first the command `su` and give your root password (or `sudo bash`, in some Linux distributions)`, you will then be root and you should then fix the access/permission problems...

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for grep, but if I understand correctly you want to search the path string for a substring. You can just use `==` or `=~` for that, as in

```
[[ "$VAR" == *"HI"* ]]     # Does "$VAR" match <stuff>HI<stuff>?
```

or

```
[[ "$VAR" =~ "HI" ]]       # Does "$VAR" contain HI?
```

Comment: Holy crap, I didn't know that `ksh` supported those!  (POSIX shell, your typical `/bin/sh`, does *not*)

Answer (score 0):

I have a variable to which a path of a file is assigned by a command,

for  example

VAR=`grep /adr filename`  - assume my filename has a line like **/adr/samp.txt**

So when I echo $VAR, it gives me the /adr/samp.txt, but gives an error for cat $VAR or with grep

I resolved this by making
VAR=$(grep /adr filename).  Then I can do cat $VAR.

I dont know whats wrong with ``

Thanks,
Adr

Answer (score 0):

[WAF's `[[ "$VAR" =~ "HI" ]]` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188208/87770) here has a great `bash`/`ksh` solution that is probably what you are looking for, but in case somebody is looking for a portable solution, here is how to do this natively within a plain POSIX shell (the base `/bin/sh`):

```bsh
[ "$VAR" != "${VAR#*HI}" ]
```

Be careful, [shell pattern syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) (aka "globbing") is *different* from POSIX regular expression syntax.

This compares the value of `$VAR` with the `${VAR#*HI}` parameter expansion, which implements [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to remove anything at its beginning up to the first instance of "HI" (given `VAR="OHIO"`, `${VAR#*HI}` would be remove the leading `OHI` and result in just `O`. `VAR="Hi, I am bob"` would be unchanged).

Due to the `!=` comparison, the return value will be *true* (`0`) when the two strings differ (meaning "HI" exists in `$VAR`) and *false* (`1`) when they are the same (meaning "HI" does not exist in `$VAR`).